# How do I reduce the size of a giant SVG file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, svg, inkscape

I'm using windows 10 X64 and QGIS 2.18.1.  My goal is to create detailed large wall prints using high density contour layers. When I export from print composer as an SVG, I create files from 10 MB to 110MB. I'm using Inkscape to manipulate the stroke/pen width and then subsequently export as a PNG. The resulting lag is disruptive. Since my goals for print size start at ~ 40" X 60" I am unsure of how much detail loss I can handle.

here is an average file (41 MB):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B49fTXAI05SweVJqOXJUZ3JTNm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The lag with inkscape presumably from the file size (each click doing anything takes minutes) but, I'm having trouble gauging where the problem is.  should I use a different vector editor? Since all I really want are the lines, am I exporting from qgis data I don't need? Are these files going to be huge no matter what?

Comment: you might want to [check out answers to this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9009305/5158630). Not tried these suggestions so not sure how well those will work with QGIS print composer output.

Comment: I used the svg cleaner: https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui/releases

Comment: It was great for svg files straight from QGIS.  But the inkscape  manipulated files resulted in an empty 1 kb file.  Otherwise it worked like a charm.  Thank you.